# Android: What is this "notification" called?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

Look at this image first

[image]

The little box that says "copied to clipboard" appears after i take a screenshot and goes away after a couple seconds.

What is this type of `Notification` call, what API level is required?

I want to display a quick message like this after a user clicks a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see the image, but I assume you're talking about `Toast`s. You might find more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

Comment: Thank you so much Forever now i thought that toast was just a way people name there textviews.

Comment: Everytime you make a question and someone solves your doubt, both for feedback and reputation, accept the answer that helped you most so other users can know what's the correct solution.